# Why won't the java String "contains" method return found?

Tags: java, string, contains

Here is the input to my function

```
"<div class=\"xbox\">TESTING<span class=\"newbox\"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"btnbox\">Use a new box</a></span></div><div class=\"cardnumber\">***-1111</div></div>"
```

When I do the below it never returns anything but -1

```
input.indexOf("cardnumber")
```

Any reason this isn't working? when I do an indexOf("div") it returns fine ... (help)

thanks guys (sorry for not posting the unit test earlier)

```
public Cart viewCart() {
        ResponseAndCookies result = service.makeHttpRequestWithUrl("https://www.xbox.com/account/fakebox/");
        String response = result.getResponse();

        String availableCreditCard = "<div class=\"cardnumber\">***";
        if (response.contains(availableCreditCard)) {
            return parseJson.parseCartAndReturnObject(response);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class XboxViewCartServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void verify_cart_works_with_valid_login() {
        FakeXboxCartParseJson jsonParser = new FakeXboxCartParseJson();
        XboxViewCartService sut = new XboxViewCartService(new FakeXboxViewCartHttpBase(), jsonParser);
        Cart cart = sut.viewCart(null);

        Assert.assertTrue(jsonParser.calledMethod);
    }

    class FakeXboxViewCartHttpBase extends XboxHttpService {
        @Override
        public ResponseAndCookies doHttpPostWithUrl(String url, ResponseAndCookies responseAndCookies, String json) {
            ResponseAndCookies result = new ResponseAndCookies();
            result.setResponse("<div class=\"xbox\">TESTING<span class=\"newbox\"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"btnbox\">Use a new box</a></span></div><div class=\"cardnumber\">***-1111</div></div>");

            return result;
        }
    }

    class FakeXboxCartParseJson extends XboxCartParseJson {
        public boolean calledMethod = false;
        @Override
        public Cart parseCartAndReturnObject(String html) {
            calledMethod = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there non-printing characters in the string? To my eye, there is no reason that `cardnumber` wouldn't be found in that input string.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code, please?

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://ideone.com/voTHj

Comment: thanks for the update to the question. What about the data returned by your endpoint, as you'd be able to get it using Firebug or something similar?

Comment: (The other question is: what are your doing to this poor XBox portal?? :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This obviously works as you provide it, so there are only 3 options:

1. There are some non-printable characters in the string;
2. There is an encoding issue when you read the input and compare;
3. There's something wrong somewhere else that we cannot see because you don't give enough code.

For the moment, the best best is item 3.

Please provide more code.

**EDIT (2011-05-23 02:20):**

Thanks for the update to your question. So, now we still cannot be sure as we're missing the data returned by your endpoint, but there's a good chance if just doesn't exactly contain `<div class="cardnumber">***`.

Do make sure as well that you specify the right headers for your request and that you use valid content type and character encoding. Please make also sure that you are not using a strange encoding on your source files, as you might be inputting non-standard `*` characters without knowing it.

Comment: Turned out to be an implementation fail on my part in the unit test (override was on the wrong method) - thanks for taking the time to help this thrashing dev!

Comment: @Toran: You're welcome. Happens to everyone, that's why it's good we're all skeptics around here :)

Comment: amen! thanks again! (any chance we could flag this for removal yet keep your rep earned?) - i only ask because the question doesn't really add much value for others :(

Comment: @Toran: I'll happily flag it for removal if you want. I don't really know what happens to my points, but it doesn't matter. Done. It's in the hands of the SO team/moderators now.